# Why is setRouteLeaveHook not visible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-dom

Using version 4.1.1 of react-router-dom I have a component wrapped with "withRouter" I have added router to the context and at runtime I see a router object in the context.  The routes are beahving as expected and the page contains a redux form.  However attempts to call setRouteLeaveHook result in:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.context.router.setRouteLeaveHook is not a
>   function

So my question is: **Why is setRouteLeaveHook not visible as a function?**

I have actually tried several ways before this, including the code from [mknabe](https://gist.github.com/mknabe/bfcb6db12ef52323954a28655801792d), but they all result in the same error.

Abbreviated code:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
...

export class MyDetail extends React.Component {
...
  componentDidMount() {
    this.context.router.setRouteLeaveHook(this.props.route, () => {
      if (true)
        return 'You have unsaved information, are you sure you want to leave this page?'
    })
  }

render() {
...
}
...
MyDetail.propTypes = {
  ...
  route: PropTypes.object,
};

MyDetail.contextTypes = { router: PropTypes.object };

const MyDetailForm = reduxForm({
  validate,
  form: 'My_detail',
  enableReinitialize: true,
})(MyDetail);
const ConnectedMyDetail = connect(mapStateToProps)(MyDetailForm);
export default withRouter(ConnectedMyDetail);
```

Comment: In v4 what you're looking for is Prompt https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Prompt . let me know if that doesn't work for you and we can flesh out an adequate solution. furthermore you don't need to put router on context. withRouter will populate router props to your component directly

Comment: Thank you so much.  Been going in circles.  Prompt works, but doesn't trigger if I am loading a different item on the same route.  Is there a way to trigger under that circumstance?  Maybe a feature of the <Link> ?

Comment: What do you mean by "different item"? You can have as many Prompt components as you need.

Comment: I mean if I have a page that displays details of a Cat, and it also contains links to the Cat's mum that will display it at the same Route, if you click the link, it loads the other Cat's details, looses any changes, and doesn't trigger the prompt.

Comment: Whether or not the prompt is triggered is completely up to you based on the value passed to `when`.

Comment: But @azium, I always made it put the prompt up regardless of incoming path ... so it is not getting triggered at a lower level.